# How to make several tables or images next to each other and exceeding margins

Tags: graphics, captions, margins

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm trying to learn the basics to survive. I've found it very hard to understand how to position several images in the same line while at the same time make them go beyond their margins. I've found a "solution" involving minipages and boxes with 0 size (which I really don't understand) but it makes captions appear weirdly. Consider my case:

```
\textbf{{\Large 3.}} Las gráficas obtenidas son las siguientes:\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\makebox[0pt][c]{
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.93\linewidth]{IV1}
\label{fig:IV1} \\
Figura 3. Gráfica I-V para la lámpara 1, formada por una sola bombilla. Se observa una relación lineal entre ambas magnitudes.
\end{minipage} \  \ 
\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{IV2}
\label{fig: IV2} Figura 4. Gráfica I-V para la lámpara 2, formada por dos bombillas. También hay una relación lineal.\\
\end{minipage}
}
```

Gives:
[image]

So they kind of overlap. It's a problem that I don't really understand what's going on even after having read several posts. So

1. How does this "empty box" work? I read that boxes are elements that are interpreted as a single unit, but it doesn't help. Why do I need to introduce a figure inside the box? Is it because it lets me give several labels to images? I would like to get how all of it works in order to arrange images in any other different situation without copying someone's code.
2. How can I fix the captions problem, that is, separe them so that they stay under the images?

Thanks.

2)

Comment: Inside a minipage, go ahead and use `\caption` (before `\label`).  Like the TARDIS, `\makebox` is bigger on the inside than the outside.  Also, `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{..}` does not need `\centering`.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- Your problem is declared width of `minipage`s. Their sum of width should be smaller or the most equal to `text width`.
- In case, that you like that image spill out of text area width, than you need to increase `\textwidth` locally. For example with ose `adjustwidth` environment determined in the `changepage` package (sorry, from your question this is not clear ). So, I guess that you are after something like this :-)

[image]

In this site you can find many similar question, so yours is actually a duplicate to them ...

- I a bit guessing what you after ...
- Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` which can be compiled as it is and which reproduce your problem,
- In MWE (Minimal Working Example) below the size of images are determined by size of `minimpage`s (therefore they have width different from zero).
- For vertical position of minipages position `[t]` should be used.
- For image caption the command `caption` should be used.
- Label  should be after caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\textbf{{\Large 3.}} 
Las gráficas obtenidas son las siguientes:
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Gráfica I-V para la lámpara 1, formada por una sola bombilla. Se observa una relación lineal entre ambas magnitudes.}
\label{fig:IV1}         % <--- label had to be after \caption
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Gráfica I-V para la lámpara 2, formada por dos bombillas. También hay una relación lineal.}
\label{fig: IV2}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

- It seems, that you, as novice, read some introductory text about LaTeX. For example [No SO Short Introduction to LaTeX](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), for inserting images in document [Floats, Figures and Captions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions), etc.
- Proposed solution woks (out of the box) because it complains with rules how to use LaTeX as are described in aforementioned documents.
- Main changes in comparison to your code fragment are described in explanation above first MWE (Minimal Working Example).
- An example, how to make images width, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage} % <--- added

\begin{document}

\textbf{{\Large 3.}} 
Las gráficas obtenidas son las siguientes:

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep} % <--- new, added
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}     % <--- changed
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Gráfica I-V para la lámpara 1, formada por una sola bombilla. Se observa una relación lineal entre ambas magnitudes.}
\label{fig:IV1}         % <--- label had to be after \caption
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Gráfica I-V para la lámpara 2, formada por dos bombillas. También hay una relación lineal.}
\label{fig: IV2}
\end{minipage}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Red lines indicate page layout. In real document consider comment in code part, which draw them!)

Comment: I'd indeed like the images to go outside the margins, exceeding \textwidth. How would I do it? Also, can you explain why this even works in the first place? I don't really get it.

Comment: @JaimeYepesdePaz, see addendum to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that lets the images protrude symmetrically outside the textblock, by an amount of `0.1\textwidth` on each side. Framelines are drawn because the `showframe` package is loaded.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}  % for '\includegraphics' macr
\usepackage{showframe} % draw framelines around textblock

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textbf{\Large 3.} 
Las gráficas obtenidas son las siguientes:
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centerline{% center the argument of this command horizontally
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.58\textwidth} % 0.58+0.04+0.58=1.20
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1}
\caption{Gráfica I-V para la lámpara 1, formada por una sola 
 bombilla. Se observa una relación lineal entre ambas magnitudes.}
\label{fig:IV1}     
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.04\textwidth}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.58\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2}
\caption{Gráfica I-V para la lámpara 2, formada por 
 dos bombillas. También hay una relación lineal.}
\label{fig: IV2}
\end{minipage}} % end of scope of \centerline directive
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```